# Angular - D3.js, Jasmine testing generated HTML

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, jasmine

I have a d3.js code:

```
var svgX = svg.append("text")
        .attr("class", "x label")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("x", graphConfig.width)
        .attr("y", graphConfig.height - 6)
        .style("font-size","16px")
        .text(keyDim);
```

And I want to test the generated html with Jasmine in the following way:

```
var svgXHtml = d3.select(angular.element('<text class="x label" text-anchor="end" x="500" y="294" style="font-size: 16px;">time</text>')[0]);
expect(svgX).toBe(svgXHtml);
```

The test fails, although `<text>...</text>` part of `svgX` and `svgXHtml` is identical. In console I see:
`Expected [ [ HTMLNode, parentNode: HTMLNode ] ] to be [ [ HTMLNode, parentNode: HTMLNode ] ]`

Just logging of `svgX` and `svgXHtml` gives:

```
LOG: [[<text class="x label" text-anchor="end" x="500" y="294" style="font-size: 16px;">time</text>]]
LOG: [[<text class="x label" text-anchor="end" x="500" y="294" style="font-size: 16px;">time</text>]]
```

Looks like identical for me, but test fails.

So, how to do it in the right way?

Comment: Can I ask you why you are using `d3.select` to pick already existing element?

Comment: Because I was trying to make `console.log()` look identical in both cases hoping that it can move me any way further down the road. If I do not do this, I will get `[ [ HTMLNode, parentNode: HTMLNode ] ]`, another one just as `HTMLNode`. So, I do not need it for anything else. My goal is just to construct html from `<text class="x label" text-anchor="end" x="500" y="294" style="font-size: 16px;">time</text>` making it equal to svgX.

Comment: Can you try to maintain selection for `svgX with `d3.select` too? Something like `d3.select('body').html('').append('text')` but selection your actual element where you appending that.

Comment: I can not do it directly in the code since it will break the app. I can try to wrap svgX in `d3.select()` right in the test, is that what you mean?

Comment: It does not help. Now I see one LOG as `[[[ ... ]]]` (svgX), another one as above.

Comment: Yes, i've expected that, try to use my updated answer with stringily. Funny - but any instance of `d3` Objects after deep-compare are not same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously each of `svgX` and `svgXHtml` are Objects and `.toBe()` method is reference to `===` comparing. So currently you are trying to compare separate instances of Object. In this case Jasmine have super method called `.toEqual()` that will compare structure of both Objects.

If `.toEqual()` tells you that deep compare did not found matches, you can try stringifying that Object for on-eye-compare:

`expect(JSON.stringify(svgX)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(svgXHtml));`

This will help to compare to totally different objects you have - `svg` instance and `d3` instance.

[image]

At least now you are free to use `.toBe()` :D

Comment: Please consider reading http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html. There is explanation of everything even for that one (`"The 'toBe' matcher compares with ==="`)

Comment: Nope, it does not work. After changing to `toEqual` I am getting the same kind of an error: `Expected [ [ HTMLNode, parentNode: HTMLNode ] ] to equal [ [ HTMLNode, parentNode: HTMLNode ] ].`

Comment: You going to compare two different instances of Objects that have own `prototype` that are different as well as `ownProperty`. Thats why any of compares will not work for that objects.

Comment: OK, but then how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Compare context of Objects instead of instances with `JSON.stringify()` on `svgX` or `svgX[0]`

Comment: OK, it worked with `JSON.stringify()` function, so I accepted the answer. However, svgXHtml looks so ugly: `JSON.stringify(d3.select(angular.element('...')))`. Are there any other easier ways I could verify HTML that I am getting from D3.js functions or I would need to do it all the time?

Comment: Can you move stringify in to expect formula?

Comment: What do you mean by `context`? How?

Comment: expect(JSON.stringify(svgX)).toEqual(JSON.stringify(svgXHtml)); As I remember it can accept not only promises

Comment: Yes, that's what I am doing right now and it is working. It is a bit cumbersome though...

Comment: You can try to move that `JSON.stringify()` method to private `function s() { ... }` so it will be looking a little bit smaller.. :D